# how to export a fastlane env to the main shell environment?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, provisioning-profile, fastlane, fastlane-match

I have a CI setup on [bitrise](https://app.bitrise.io/) that's sort of like this:

```sh
# first script
fastlane match appstore
```

```sh
# second script
bash mycommands.sh
```

Now `mycommands.sh` needs access to one of the outputs of the first script, specifically the UDID of the provisioning profile that was pulled. If I do the `match` step inside a lane, the UDID would be available as `ENV['sigh_com.******_development']`, but it's not available to the environment outside the first script. So how can I make it available to commands that run after the first script has completed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to wrap both within a fastlane lane:

Fastfile:

```rb
lane :do_something do |options|
  match(type: 'appstore')
  sh "mycommands.sh"
end
```

Quick'n'dirty way (I REALLY don't recommend relying on this as it's fragile for a number of reasons, but if you need this for something quick):

```sh
fastlane match appstore | grep 'Profile UUID' | awk '{ print $7 }'
```

Comment: That's right but it'll require some changes to my CI setup that I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: You could always run `fastlane match appstore | tee | grep 'Profile UUID'` to at least get the lines where this is output, but be warned, this won't be safe and will output multiple lines if you have more than one bundleId.

Comment: Oh nice thanks for that, definitely an option. Do you know of a quick addition to that command that would extract the ID from the resulting output? That command you posted includes the full line from fastlane.

Comment: See my edit above